# Visual Force Quicksave Action is Overwriting Previous Record

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I created a form using visualforce. I needed a save action that does not refresh the page so I set the rerender to null. However, when I click save the form saves successfully, but when I enter new data into the form and save again the previous record is overwritten by the new one.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!quicksave}" value="Save" rerender="null" />
```

If the page is allowed to refresh it will not overwrite the previous record, but a page refresh is not acceptable to the user.
Is this just a behavior of Quicksave? Documentation is unclear. Do I need to write my own controller to not have it overwrite?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that quicksave "Inserts a new record or updates an existing record if it is currently in context". So, if you want to save a new record when quicksave is called you need to implement your custom page controller (or write extension for the standard one) and overwrite this behavior.